# how to style rows with a specific position for each column (CSS)

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this output (it is an invoice)

[image]

in the image example, there are 3 rows in each column bounded by vertical black lines, if the content is larger, it must create a new line as shown in the second element and pushing the rows below

HTML looks like

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="amount">3</div>
        <div class="description"> Viajes a mexico </div>
        <div class="unit_price">$ 1,900.00</div> 
        <div class="total">$5,700.00</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <div class="amount"></div>
        <div class="description">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
        <div class="unit_price"></div> 
        <div class="total"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <div class="amount">1</div>
        <div class="description">gastos</div>
        <div class="unit_price">$22</div> 
        <div class="total"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I used **position: absolute;** to set **left** property in some columns but if I use position absolute in all of them **(A)**, the rows is drawn on top another one, so I have to set that property only to the last column

[image]

I have no experience in CSS, what has solved the problem for me is the following code but I would like a second opinion

CSS

```
div.items{
    position: fixed;
    top: 7.85cm;
    left: 1.2cm;
    width: 19.6cm;
    height: 4.5cm;
    border: 0px solid black;
}
div.item{ 
    display: flex;
    border: 0px solid blue;  
}

div.amount{
    left: 0.2cm;
    width: 2.1cm;
    border: 0px solid black;
}

div.descripcion{
    left: 2.4cm;
    width: 10cm;
    border: 0px solid black;
}

div.unit_price{
    left: 12.5cm;
    width: 1.5cm;
    border: 0px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

div.total{
    left: 17cm;
    width: 2cm;
    border: 0px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}
```

***the question is:***
How can I use the absolute property in all columns without the rows being drawn on top of each other?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a table for table-like layout ?

Comment: there is no reason, it could be a table, but I was trying to do it that way since the position of the columns is variable, for example the last column has a space that must be respected, that's why I was trying to do it with an absolute position,  but if with table layout, you can leave this space between the two columns, that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position` would be the **worst** way of laying this out.

If you can't use a `table` (and you should) use CSS Tables.

```css
.items {
  display: table;
}

.item {
  display: table-row;
}

.item div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.unit_price {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="amount">3</div>
    <div class="description"> Viajes a mexico </div>
    <div class="unit_price">$ 1,900.00</div>
    <div class="total">$5,700.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="amount"></div>
    <div class="description">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
    <div class="unit_price"></div>
    <div class="total"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="amount">1</div>
    <div class="description">gastos</div>
    <div class="unit_price">$22</div>
    <div class="total"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to respect the position of the columns, the tables draw one column followed by another, in the first image it is shown that there is a space between the green box and the red box (last two columns)

Comment: if I use tables I would have to add columns to the table to be able to separate and set the width of each column, it sounds like a possible solution, but I would like not to have to add columns but if there is no other way I will have to use that solution